# SQLite does not check Data Types

Tags: python, sqlite, sqldatatypes

Dear Stack Overflow Community,

I have a little problem here with starting my first attempt to Database-Design.

I try to make some Kind of a tabular and try to check out the Basic functions; writing with Python3 and SQLite3.

My question is quite simple, I have a few lines:

```
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test(a INTEGER, argument DATE)')
```

Now I can just write:

```
cur.execute('insert into test (a, argument) values (?,?)', "bla", "blabla")
```

Without getting an error message; shouldn't this command be automatically forbidden by SQL when you define the allowed datatypes in the `CREATE TABLE` statement?

Full code is here: http://codepad.org/kf4gZB7m

Comment: Welcome to SO, Update your question with the code in the question

Answer (score 4):

This is a feature, not a bug. SQLite uses dynamic typing. See https://sqlite.org/faq.html#q3

Comment: Okay thank you for the answer! Is this Feature connected to some Performance losses or higher memory consumption? And if yes, is there a way to disable this feature?

Comment: Don't know about memory consumption but there is certainly no way to make SQLite more type-strict. You'd need a different SQL implementation for that.

Comment: SQLite often uses less memory and is faster than other DBs, but comparing embedded and client/servers DBs does not really make sense. You can [add manual checks](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sqlite/5252/data-types) if you really need them.

Comment: It's a pretty terrible feature. There should at least be a way to turn on proper type checking. :-/

Comment: @Timmmm there is now: https://www.sqlite.org/stricttables.html

Answer (score 2):

This feature is **Type Affinity**:

> SQL database engines that use rigid typing will usually try to
>   automatically convert values to the appropriate datatype. The
>   important idea here is that the type is recommended, not required.

Docs: https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity

Answer (score 1):

As of version 3.37.0 (2021-11-27), SQLite supports a [strict typing mode](https://www.sqlite.org/stricttables.html) to fix its most infamous feature. It must be enabled per-table with the keyword `STRICT`.

```
> CREATE TABLE t(a INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, b TEXT) STRICT;
> INSERT INTO t VALUES (2, "foo");
> INSERT INTO t VALUES ("foo", "bar");
Runtime error: datatype mismatch (20)
```

For better or for worse, SQLite will still try to silently coerce values to match the column type even in strict mode:

```
INSERT INTO t VALUES ("1", 2);   -- A-okay!
```

However, if no lossless coercion is possible, like using `"foo"` as an integer above, an error is raised.